# Feature Configuration with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, configuration, feature-selection

I'm trying to configure a set of features in code, as depicted on this image:
[Feature Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amU5x.png)

I can create a dataframe just fine from a csv file we were provided, then create a Regression Tree (partially) using these lines:

```
df=pd.read_csv('Assignment_4_Performance_Measurements.csv', encoding='utf-8')

X=df[['Encryption', 'AES', 'Blowfish', 'rar', 'zip',
      'Signature', 'Timestamp', 'Segmentation', 'einhundertMB', 'einGB']]
y=df['Performance']
```

Now, the problem is I don't know how to configure XOR gates in this dataframe, e.g., If you select Encryption, you can select either AES OR Blowfish. Same for Segmentation, and Algorithm.

I'd be really helpful if you could provide help as I can't find any helpful info online.